# delete string ending with a pattern for each column

Tags: awk, sed, perl

I would like to delete all entries with (L=6), (L=7).....(L=12) occurring in a file randomly the following format;

my input file:

```
TRINITY_DN1910_c0_g1_i13    GO:0005975(L=2) GO:0006022(L=4) GO:0006026(L=5) GO:0006030(L=9) GO:0006032(L=11)    GO:0006040(L=6)
TRINITY_DN1452_c0_g1_i11    GO:0005975(L=3) GO:0006022(L=9) GO:0006026(L=12)    GO:0006030(L=2) GO:0006032(L=4) GO:0006040(L=5)
```

The file is tab delimited.

Expected output

```
TRINITY_DN1910_c0_g1_i13    GO:0005975(L=2) GO:0006022(L=4) GO:0006026(L=5)
TRINITY_DN1452_c0_g1_i11    GO:0005975(L=3) GO:0006030(L=2) GO:0006032(L=4) GO:0006040(L=5)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what you've tried, where you are stuck, and what your question is.

Comment: Wll the entries you want to delete always be contiguous numbers like `6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12` or could there be holes like `6, 8, 11, 12`?

Comment: I want to delete all the GO entries with (L=[>5]) retain everything else

Comment: You should have said THAT in your question instead of `I would like to delete all entries with (L=6), (L=7).....(L=12)`. The end result might be the same for your current specific data but deleting everything `>5` is a different problem from deleting within a specific range.

Comment: Don't change it now though as you already have answers to the question you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `sed` as follows:

```
sed 's/GO:[^   ]*(L=[6-9])//g
     s/GO:[^ ]*(L=1[0-2])//g' filename
```

You can enter the tab character by pressing `<ctrl-v><tab>`.  That is what I have in square brackets starting with `^`.

Comment: Thanks @Ed Morton, It works! I added removal of multiple tabs                                                                                               
sed 's/GO:[^\t]*(L=[6-9])//g' test.txt | sed 's/GO:[^\t]*(L=1[0-2])//g' | sed -r 's:\t+:\t:g' >l.txt

Comment: @alexkiarie, It is bad practice to call the editor several times in the pipeline: `sed 's/\s*\S*(L=\([6-9]\|1[0-2]\))//g' file`

Comment: thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN {
        for (i=6; i<=12; i++) {
            re = re sep i
            sep = "|"
        }
        re = "\t[^\t]+[(]L=(" re ")[)]"
    }
    {
        gsub(re,"")
        print
    }
' file
TRINITY_DN1910_c0_g1_i13        GO:0005975(L=2) GO:0006022(L=4) GO:0006026(L=5)
TRINITY_DN1452_c0_g1_i11        GO:0005975(L=3) GO:0006030(L=2) GO:0006032(L=4) GO:0006040(L=5)
```

If you have any other contiguous range of numbers to deal with just change the start/end numbers in the loop. If you have non contiguous numbers just set `re` in the `BEGIN` however makes sense for those numbers, e.g. an option might be to replace the loop with `re = "7|12|957|1045"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub(/\s*\S*L=([6-9]|1[0-9])\)/, "")}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `FS` to the what you need and when this match rebuild the whole line :

```
awk -F'GO:[0-9]*[(]L=([6-9]|1[0-2])[)] *' '{
    s = ""
    for(i = 1; i<= NF; i++) 
        s = s ? s $i : $i
    print s
}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne '.=words; print .[0] ~ "\t"; \
      put $_.skip.grep( { / "(L=" (\d+) ")" $ / && $0 < 6 } ).join: "\t";'
```

Sample Input (tab-separated columns):

```
TRINITY_DN1910_c0_g1_i13    GO:0005975(L=2) GO:0006022(L=4) GO:0006026(L=5) GO:0006030(L=9) GO:0006032(L=11)    GO:0006040(L=6)
TRINITY_DN1452_c0_g1_i11    GO:0005975(L=3) GO:0006022(L=9) GO:0006026(L=12)    GO:0006030(L=2) GO:0006032(L=4) GO:0006040(L=5)
```

Sample Output (tab-separated columns):

```
TRINITY_DN1910_c0_g1_i13    GO:0005975(L=2) GO:0006022(L=4) GO:0006026(L=5)
TRINITY_DN1452_c0_g1_i11    GO:0005975(L=3) GO:0006030(L=2) GO:0006032(L=4) GO:0006040(L=5)
```

- Briefly, lines are read in using the `-ne` non-autoprinting linewise
  flags,
- Input is broken into whitespace-delimited columns using the
  `.=words` routine wherein the `.=` operator saves the resultant
  elements back into Raku's `$_` topic variable ( `.=words` is
  shorthand for `$_ = $_.words` ),
- In the second statement, the first column is printed, followed by
  `\t` tab, and
- Finally in the third statement, the first element is skipped (since
  it has already been printed), and `grep` is used to return elements
  that first match `"(L=" (\d+) ")" $` and then `&& $0 < 6` have the `$0`
  capture value less than 6.

https://raku.org

Answer (score -1):

```
sed -e  "s/GO:[0-9]*(L=[6-9])/ /g" -e "s/GO:[0-9]*(L=[0-9]\{2,\})/ /g" FILENAME
```

OUTPUT

```
TRINITY_DN1910_c0_g1_i13    GO:0005975(L=2) GO:0006022(L=4) GO:0006026(L=5)         
TRINITY_DN1452_c0_g1_i11    GO:0005975(L=3)        GO:0006030(L=2) GO:0006032(L=4) GO:0006040(L=5)
```